# How to add data into sql db using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have 2 input fields "User" and "Comment" and I want the user input to be saved asynchronously using AJAX, so no refreshing. So far I've gotten it to add a new row to the DB, but for some reason it is empty. I believe the reason is I am not appending the values correctly.

HTML(JS is in-between head tags):

```
<p>User: <input type="text" id="userName" /></p>
<p>Comment : <input type="text" id="comment" /></p>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="callServer();" />
```

JS:

```
function callServer(){
  var usr = document.getElementById("user").value;
  var cmnt = document.getElementById("comment").value;
  var ajaxRequest = XMLHttpRequest();

  ajaxRequest.open("POST", "insert.php", true);
  ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// Setting variables for the elements
$user = $_POST['user'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

// Establishing connection and selecting db    
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('local',$con);

// Doing the query for the insert
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO content (Title, Article)
VALUES('$user', '$comment')");

mysql_query($query, $con);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Use PDO else change line to $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO content (Title, Article)
VALUES('".$user."', '".$comment."')");

Comment: Your ajax call isn't actually sending anything. You're doing a POST, but fail to actually included any data in it. `.send(null)` <--- you're sending a null value as your data.

Comment: Have you checked $POST to see if its available.  Have you output any mysql errors?

Comment: additionally, you might want to sanitize you input i.e. use `mysql_real_escape_string($user)` instead only using $user in your query... same goes for `$comment`. otherwise, you'll found yourself with who knows what in your db very soon ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input ID is `userName` but you are targeting `user`.

Change to:

```
var usr = document.getElementById("userName").value;
```

You are also sending `null` with the ajax request, you should be sending your data:

```
var params = "user=" + encodeURIComponent(usr) + "&comments=" + encodeURIComponent(cmnt);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
ajaxRequest.send(params);
```

Also, you should include the content-type header - as above.

Finally, the mysql_* library is deprecated, you should use a modern API such as PDO or MySQLi for any new development. Because you're using this library you need to escape post data for SQL Injection:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
```

If you use a modern API, you can do parameterised queries which don't require you to manually escape anything.

Also just noticed, remove this line:

```
mysql_query($query, $con);
```

You have already executed the query on the line before that. This line is useless and will fail, it is trying to execute another query using the result resource of the first query.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start looking a little into Jquery, it helps a lot on the javascript/Ajax part.

The problem here is that you are never sending the variables in the AJAX call, you need something like this:

```
ajaxRequest.send(postvariables);
```